# How to handle the jsx as a variable to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I'm want to use some React code in my app and don't have the possibility to use an external bundler.

Because I'm using the browsers internal support for javascript modules I have to use `type="module"` within the script tag so there's no possibility
for using babel-standalone on the same file because it needs it's own `type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,stage-2,react"` attribute.

index.html

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

main.js

```
import './vendor/js/react.js';
import './vendor/js/react-dom.js';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(App),
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Right now this won't work because without babel the jsx within the render() method cannot be transpiled by the browser.

I tried some dirty workaround when I created a variable containing the jsx and transpiled it using babel but there seems no way to make the components render() method use this transpiled variable.

index.html

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="./vendor/js/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
...
```

main.js

```
var jsxContent = `<h1>Hello</h1>`;
var jsContent = Babel.transform(jsxContent, { presets: ['react'] }).code;

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return jsContent
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(App),
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Using React.createElement within the component render() method seems to work but it's a mess in bigger components.

Isn't there a workaround to use jsx in this case?

Comment: Maybe react/babel cdn libraries could work? React: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react , Babel: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core. Then, maybe you can put them in the index.html file.

Comment: But how could this solve my problem? Using this cdn libraries includes the react and react-dom scripts but besides these two I want to make use of the import module capabilities for other js files (e.g. other react components) and babel-standalone cannot provide module support. So I need a solution that includes es6 modules and babel-standalone (for jsx transpilation) at the same time.

Comment: Instead of imports  i believe you can do 'var file = require('file.js')'

Comment: Obviously there is no 'require' support -> 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require'